# Slater-type condition for quasi-convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose:

1. $U$ is an open, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$,
2. $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable on $U$,
3. $G: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuously differentiable on $U$,
4. $A$ is a $k \times n$ matrix and $c \in \mathbb{R}^k$
5. $B$ is a $l \times n$ matrix and $d \in \mathbb{R}^l$

Consider the following minimization problem, denoted as $(P)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize } &f(x) \\
\text{subjected to } x &\in U, \\
G(x) &\leq 0, \\
Ax &\leq c, \\
Bx &= d
\end{align*}
$$

We say $(P)$ satisfies the **Slater's condition** if there exists $x_0 \in U$ such that

$$
\begin{align*}
G(x_0) &\ll 0, \\
Ax_0 &\leq c, \\
Bx_0 &= d
\end{align*}
$$

where the symbol $\ll$ means "all components are strictly less than".

**Theorem:**

A theorem says that if:

1. $f$ is a convex function,
2. every component of $G$ is a convex function,
3. $(P)$ satisfies the Slater's condition,

then any solution to $(P)$ satisfies the KKT conditions.

**Questions:**

1. If $f$ is merely a **quasi-convex** function, is there a Slater-type condition that guarantees any solution to $(P)$ would satisfy the KKT conditions?
2. Continuing with question 1, what if $G$ is merely quasi-convex, while $f$ remains convex?
3. Continuing with questions 1 and 2, what if both $f$ and $G$ are merely quasi-convex?

Comment: The convexity of $f$ is not used when one proves KKT under Slater.

Comment: @daw Could you give a reference? I would like to see how to prove KKT without the convexity of $f$.

Comment: There  is a proof in the (German)  book by Geiger/Kanzow on constrained optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the questioner. I have found a [lecture note on optimization by John Nachbar](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.wustl.edu/dist/3/2139/files/2019/09/kkt.pdf), which answers my question.

In section 4.5, it is stated that if:

1. $f$ is any $C^1$ function,
2. for $1 \leq i \leq m$, $g_i$ is quasi-convex,
3. $(P)$ satisfies the Slater's condition,
4. $x^*$ is a solution to $(P)$,
5. for $1 \leq i \leq m$, $ \nabla g_i(x^*) \neq 0 $,

then $x^*$ satisfies the constraint qualification of KKT conditions.